# how to write vb code for custom paging and custom sorting in sql and asp:repeater

Tags: asp.net

pl give vb code for custom paging and sorting in asp:repeater using stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

Here is step [one](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510021915/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx) and [two](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/032206-1.aspx) from 4guys that gives a very clear explanation along with zip download available of all code in VB and sample t-sql too.

It deals with ObjectDataSource  from which then it should be straigtforward enough to bind your repeater to.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to give a little bit more information than just that. If you're using ASP.NEt 1.x, the code will be a whole lot different to that for ASP.NET 2.0 or higher. Indeed, what do you mean by 'custom' paging and sorting? You could use VS to create a DataSource that calls the stored procedure and does the paging and sorting for you and then bind the datasource control to the repeater.