# how to sort repeater according to any content?

Tags: asp.net

Hello I   have an asp.net application where i am getting value from twitter and binding that data to a repeater. There is column name "rate" where user can rate with star rating.

I am not storing this values in any database.

I want this functionality that when i will click on rate it will sort repeater value according to star rate without changing the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very similar to a previously asked (and answered) question.  See this post:
[how to write vb code for custom paging and custom sorting in sql and asp:repeater](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/253190/how-to-write-vb-code-for-custom-paging-and-custom-sorting-in-sql-and-asprepeater)

I would read the articles suggested in the first answer and go from there.